# If there's a human-level civilization in a nearby star system, would we detect it?

Tags: space, hard-science, fermi-paradox

So, I'm not into writing or creating any new worlds, but this question (or a set of questions) was bothering me for a while and I thought it's a good place to ask.

1. If there exists an alien civilization in a nearby star system (i. e. Alpha Centauri) and it has a similar technology level to ours (producing the same amount of radio noise), would we be able to detect it?
2. Are we at this point 100% sure there are no such civilizations in nearby star systems?
3. If there's a civilization nearby with similar technology to ours (or more advanced but still scientifically plausible) do they already know that we're here?

Comment: Also worth reading: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17765/from-how-far-away-could-our-seti-searches-detect-and-recognize-our-technological

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. We have a 1 question per post policy, while you have 3 questions here, and I am not fully sure they are about worldbuilding. Moreover, you are using the hard science tag, are you sure about it? Please take the [tour] and visit the [help], then narrow down your question and make it fit our scope.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the linked questions. That's basically what I've been looking for, so this one can be closed.

Comment: You should have got a notification about the duplicate. If  you accept the suggestion, the question will be closed as duplicate automatically.